# Sorting of array without changing the order of some particular item

Tags: javascript

I want to sort this array like that all the four year in the top comes at last without changing the order of others and it should be done without using regex.
Note, the number of years are not fixed in this case may be in other iteration number of year is only 2.

I have tried to sort it and reverse it's working but this change the order of others.

```
[ '2019',
  '2020',
  '2021',
  '2022',
  '2023',
  '_id',
  'Tender Ref Number',
  'Tender Number',
  'Additional Information',
  'Tender Type',
  'Country Exchange Rate',
  'Start Date',
  'End Date',
  'Submission Closing Date',
  'Result Date',
  'Country',
  'Region',
  'Distributer Name',
  'Franchise Name',
  'Account Name',
  'Local Account Name',
  'Win/Lost',
  'SAP Material Code',
  'ICC Code',
  'Quantity',
  'Description',
  'Standard Cost Per SAP Unit',
  'Tender Price Local',
  'Tender Price USD',
  'Total Sales',
  'Tender Currency',
  'quantity_distribution',
  'Approvers' ]

[ '_id',
  'Tender Ref Number',
  'Tender Number',
  'Additional Information',
  'Tender Type',
  'Country Exchange Rate',
  'Start Date',
  'End Date',
  'Submission Closing Date',
  'Result Date',
  'Country',
  'Region',
  'Distributer Name',
  'Franchise Name',
  'Account Name',
  'Local Account Name',
  'Win/Lost',
  'SAP Material Code',
  'ICC Code',
  'Quantity',
  'Description',
  'Standard Cost Per SAP Unit',
  'Tender Price Local',
  'Tender Price USD',
  'Total Sales',
  'Tender Currency',
  'quantity_distribution',
  'Approvers',
  '2019',
  '2020',
  '2021',
  '2022',
  '2023',]
```

Comment: The best way is using regex. Why not?

Comment: I think to do that but in our project we are not allowed to use regex.
If you have some other solution then please help me with this

Comment: For the future, post what code you have tried and we will be able to assist you in solving the problem. You will not learn if every time you get stuck, you just come here and ask someone else to solve it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that after **n number of years**, the next item will be `_id` in the array. You can [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the array till `_id` and [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) it at the end.

```js
let arr = [ '2019', '2020', '2021', '2022', '2023', '_id', 'Tender Ref Number', 'Tender Number', 'Additional Information', 'Tender Type', 'Country Exchange Rate', 'Start Date', 'End Date', 'Submission Closing Date', 'Result Date', 'Country', 'Region', 'Distributer Name', 'Franchise Name', 'Account Name', 'Local Account Name', 'Win/Lost', 'SAP Material Code', 'ICC Code', 'Quantity', 'Description', 'Standard Cost Per SAP Unit', 'Tender Price Local', 'Tender Price USD', 'Total Sales', 'Tender Currency', 'quantity_distribution', 'Approvers' ];
  
arr = arr.concat(arr.splice(0, arr.indexOf('_id')));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) & [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to check if the element is a year (number) and the `...` spread operator:

```js
var data = [ '2019', '2020', '2021', '2022', '2023', '_id', 'Tender Ref Number', 'Tender Number', 'Additional Information', 'Tender Type', 'Country Exchange Rate', 'Start Date', 'End Date', 'Submission Closing Date', 'Result Date', 'Country', 'Region', 'Distributer Name', 'Franchise Name', 'Account Name', 'Local Account Name', 'Win/Lost', 'SAP Material Code', 'ICC Code', 'Quantity', 'Description', 'Standard Cost Per SAP Unit', 'Tender Price Local', 'Tender Price USD', 'Total Sales', 'Tender Currency', 'quantity_distribution', 'Approvers' ];

let years = data.splice(0, data.filter((ele) => !isNaN(ele)).length);
data = [...data, ...years];
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let a = [ '2019',
  '2020',
  '2021',
  '2022',
  '2023',
  '_id',
  'Tender Ref Number',
  'Tender Number',
  'Additional Information',
  'Tender Type',
  'Country Exchange Rate',
  'Start Date',
  'End Date',
  'Submission Closing Date',
  'Result Date',
  'Country',
  'Region',
  'Distributer Name',
  'Franchise Name',
  'Account Name',
  'Local Account Name',
  'Win/Lost',
  'SAP Material Code',
  'ICC Code',
  'Quantity',
  'Description',
  'Standard Cost Per SAP Unit',
  'Tender Price Local',
  'Tender Price USD',
  'Total Sales',
  'Tender Currency',
  'quantity_distribution',
  'Approvers' ];
let years = a.filter(elem => !isNaN(Number(elem));
years = years.sort((a,b) => a-b);
let finalArr = a.filter(elem => isNaN(Number(elem));
finalArr.concat(years);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the years can be on any place of the array, then you could use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) this way:

```js
const input = [ 
  '2019', '2020', '2021', '2022', '2023', '_id', 'Tender Ref Number',
  'Tender Number', 'Additional Information', 'Tender Type',
  'Country Exchange Rate', 'Start Date', '2024', 'End Date',
  'Submission Closing Date', 'Result Date', 'Country', 'Region',
  'Distributer Name', 'Franchise Name', 'Account Name', 'Local Account Name',
  'Win/Lost', 'SAP Material Code', 'ICC Code', 'Quantity', 'Description',
  'Standard Cost Per SAP Unit', 'Tender Price Local', '2025',
  'Tender Price USD', 'Total Sales', 'Tender Currency',
  'quantity_distribution', 'Approvers'];

 let res = input.reduce(
     (acc, curr) => (isNaN(curr) ? acc[0].push(curr) : acc[1].push(curr), acc),
     [[],[]]
 );
 
 console.log(res[0].concat(res[1]));
```